# Time difference in rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I'm writing a simple class to parse strings into relative dates.

```
module RelativeDate
  class InvalidString < StandardError; end
  class Parser
    REGEX = /([0-9]+)_(day|week|month|year)_(ago|from_now)/

    def self.to_time(value)
      if captures = REGEX.match(value)
        captures[1].to_i.send(captures[2]).send(captures[3])
      else
        raise InvalidString, "#{value} could not be parsed"
      end
    end

  end
end
```

The code seems to work fine.

Now when I try my specs I get a time difference only in year and month

```
require 'spec_helper'
describe RelativeDate::Parser do
  describe "#to_time" do

    before do
      Timecop.freeze
    end

    ['day','week','month','year'].each do |type|
      it "should parse #{type} correctly" do
        RelativeDate::Parser.to_time("2_#{type}_ago").should == 2.send(type).ago
        RelativeDate::Parser.to_time("2_#{type}_from_now").should == 2.send(type).from_now
      end
    end

    after do
      Timecop.return
    end

  end
end
```

Output

```
..FF

Failures:

  1) RelativeDate::Parser#to_time should parse year correctly
     Failure/Error: RelativeDate::Parser.to_time("2_#{type}_ago").should == 2.send(type).ago
       expected: Wed, 29 Aug 2012 22:40:14 UTC +00:00
            got: Wed, 29 Aug 2012 10:40:14 UTC +00:00 (using ==)
       Diff:
       @@ -1,2 +1,2 @@
       -Wed, 29 Aug 2012 22:40:14 UTC +00:00
       +Wed, 29 Aug 2012 10:40:14 UTC +00:00

     # ./spec/lib/relative_date/parser_spec.rb:11:in `(root)'

  2) RelativeDate::Parser#to_time should parse month correctly
     Failure/Error: RelativeDate::Parser.to_time("2_#{type}_ago").should == 2.send(type).ago
       expected: Sun, 29 Jun 2014 22:40:14 UTC +00:00
            got: Mon, 30 Jun 2014 22:40:14 UTC +00:00 (using ==)
       Diff:
       @@ -1,2 +1,2 @@
       -Sun, 29 Jun 2014 22:40:14 UTC +00:00
       +Mon, 30 Jun 2014 22:40:14 UTC +00:00

     # ./spec/lib/relative_date/parser_spec.rb:11:in `(root)'

Finished in 0.146 seconds
4 examples, 2 failures

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/lib/relative_date/parser_spec.rb:10 # RelativeDate::Parser#to_time should parse year correctly
rspec ./spec/lib/relative_date/parser_spec.rb:10 # RelativeDate::Parser#to_time should parse month correctly
```

The first one seems like a time zone issue but the other one is even a day apart? I'm really clueless on this one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a fascinating problem!

First, this has nothing to do with Timecop or RSpec. The problem can be reproduced in the Rails console, as follows:

```
2.0.0-p247 :001 > 2.months.ago
 => Mon, 30 Jun 2014 20:46:19 UTC +00:00 
2.0.0-p247 :002 > 2.months.send(:ago)
DEPRECATION WARNING: Calling #ago or #until on a number (e.g. 5.ago) is deprecated and will be removed in the future, use 5.seconds.ago instead. (called from irb_binding at (irb):2)
 => Wed, 02 Jul 2014 20:46:27 UTC +00:00
```

[Note: This answer uses the example of `months`, but the same is true for the alias `month` as well as `year` and `years`.]

Rails adds the `month` method to the `Integer` class, returning an `ActiveSupport::Duration` object, which is a "proxy object" containing a `method_missing` method which redirects any calls to the `method_missing` method of the "value" it is serving as a proxy for.

When you call `ago` directly, it's handled by the `ago` method in the `Duration` class itself. When you try to invoke `ago` via `send`, however, `send` is not defined in `Duration` and is not defined in the `BasicObject` that all proxy objects inherit from, so the `method_missing` method of Rails' `Duration` is invoked which in turn calls `send` on the integer "value" of the proxy, resulting in the invocation of `ago` in `Numeric`. In your case, this results in a change of date equal to `2*30` days.

The only methods you have to work with are those defined by `Duration` itself and those defined by `BasicObject`. The latter are as follows:

```
2.0.0-p247 :023 > BasicObject.instance_methods
 => [:==, :equal?, :!, :!=, :instance_eval, :instance_exec, :__send__, :__id__]
```

In addition to the `instance_eval` you discovered, you can use `__send__`.

Here's the definition of `method_missing` from `duration.rb`

```
  def method_missing(method, *args, &block) #:nodoc:
    value.send(method, *args, &block)
  end
```

`value` in this case refers to the number of seconds in the `Duration` object. If you redefine `method_missing` to special case `ago`, you can get your test to pass.  Or you can alias `send` to `__send__` as follows:

```
class ActiveSupport::Duration
  alias send __send__
end
```

Here's another example of how this `method_missing` method from `Duration` works:

```
macbookair1:so1 palfvin$ rails c
Loading development environment (Rails 4.1.1)
irb: warn: can't alias context from irb_context.
2.0.0-p247 :001 > class ActiveSupport::Duration
2.0.0-p247 :002?>   def foo
2.0.0-p247 :003?>     'foobar'
2.0.0-p247 :004?>     end
2.0.0-p247 :005?>   end
 => nil 
2.0.0-p247 :006 > 2.months.foo
 => "foobar" 
2.0.0-p247 :007 > 2.months.respond_to?(:foo)
 => false 
2.0.0-p247 :008 >
```

You can call the newly defined `foo` directly, but because `BasicObject` doesn't implement `respond_to?`, you can't "test" that the method is defined there. For the same reason, `method(:ago)` on a `Duration` object returns `#<Method: Fixnum(Numeric)#ago>` because that's the `ago` method defined on `value`.

Comment: It seems interesting indeed. I will have to play with it a bit to fully understand what you are saying.

Comment: I've added a little more explanation. Please let me know what other information you are looking for.